# Should i orphan OpenCL buffers?

Tags: opengl, opencl

In **OpenGL** it is a common practice to orphan buffers that are used frequently. Ideally the drivers notices that a buffer of the same size is requested and if possible returns the old buffer if it is not needed anymore. The buffer only allocates new memory when the old buffer is still in use and can't be reused.

In **OpenCL** (on NVIDIA Hardware using the latest developer drivers) i am not sure about this technic. I got a 256kB buffer that is handled by the c++ wrapper refcounting which i reallocate frequently. Most of the time this works fine but in some cases OpenCL throws a CL_OUT_OF_MEMORY error while allocating a new buffer.

Do you think that i should switch my approach (e.g. using a constant number of buffers)? Or should i investigate in an other possible cause for this problem?

Kind regards,
Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCL uses the C semantics for memory allocation and deallocation. As such, it will not automatically reuse buffers. You *have* to explicitly release a buffer and allocate a new buffer later. Alternatively, it seems to be a good practice to reuse buffers manually. Allocation can be a quite expensive operation.

Comment: I am not sure about that. OpenCL uses C semantics but inherits some attributes and technics from OpenGL. Using the cpp wrapper library (cl.hpp) allocation and reallocation will look like this: // init cl::Buffer b = cl::Buffer(attribs); // reinit b = cl::Buffer(other attribs) ... now the wrapper is doing the reallocation work ... but the OpenCL implementation has to have its own memory managment. And that could reuse buffers of the same size.

Comment: If you "reinit" a buffer like that, you are creating a memory leak. That doesn't reinit, but creates another buffer and loses the reference to the previous buffer. Losing the reference doesn't mean it'll get freed or reused! Don't do this.

Comment: sorry for disagree with you but the c++ OpenCL wrapper implements a ref counted system that frees OpenCL resources when the c++ object gets destroyed.

Comment: Yeah, you're right - I forgot this is C++. :) However, my first point remains: memory is not implicitly reused by OpenCL. This can only happen after it has been released. If that release happens with reference counting or the like doesn't matter. The OpenCL implementation *might* return the same block of memory if you allocate a similarly sized buffer, but this is an implementation-specific detail.

Comment: ok ... i've changed my code to reuse the memory ... but i'd guess that if the vendor implements OpenGL to reuse memory they will implement OpenCL the same way